# Memory usage on select for large number of rows

Tags: postgresql, performance, memory, query-performance

I am trying to dump the entire contents of a large table, from the command line using `pqsl`, but am running into a problem where memory usage goes up, to the point where the process is killed, *before* any data is even dumped.

**What I don't understand is: why isn't the query returning results *immediately*, and completing without running out of memory?**

Here is an explanation of exactly what I'm attempting:

I have a table, say:

```
CREATE TABLE big
(
  id integer,
  rand double precision
)
```

A large number of rows is inserted (50 million):

```
insert into big 
  select generate_series(1, 50000000) AS id, random();
```

The query plan to select every row looks like (not surprisingly):

```
$ psql -d big -c "explain select * from big;"

                       QUERY PLAN                           
----------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on big  (cost=0.00..924326.24 rows=50000124 width=12)
(1 row)
```

I then attempt to dump the contents to file:

```
$ psql -d big -c "select * from big;" > big.dump
```

As I said above, this command is failing before any data is written, seemingly by taking up an ever increasing amount of memory before being killed by the OS (by "OOM killer").

*Note: I understand I could use `pg_dump` to accomplish something similar, but in reality, my query is more complex than this - specifically, I would like to encode each row as JSON when dumping*.

Some configuration details:

- postgresql version = 9.3.4
- work_mem = 1MB
- shared_buffers = 128MB
- effective_cache_size = 128MB

Comment: Although this doesn't answer the question, I was able to accomplish the task at hand using the `COPY` command: `psql -d big -c "copy (select * from big) to stdout" > big.dump`

Comment: Which process exactly gets killed? The `psql` process or the Postgres backend process for your connection? I guess the client (`psql`) buffers the result somehow (or forces the backend process to do so) When you use `copy` the data is never transferred to the client (the `psql` program) because this is all done on the server side.

Comment: Looks like the `psql` process, from syslog: `Out of memory: Kill process 26465 (psql)`.  FYI: I'm running the client on the same machine as the server.

Comment: It doesn't matter _where_ `psql` runs - it's still a "client" to the server. Does this also happen when you use the `\o` command to write the output to a file? In that case `psql` "knows" that you don't need to display the data, maybe it takes retrieves the data more efficiently then.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default, the results are entirely buffered in memory for two reasons:

1) Unless using the `-A` option, output rows are **aligned** so the output cannot start until psql knows the maximum length of each column, which implies visiting every row (which also takes a significant time in addition to lots of memory).

2) Unless specifying a `FETCH_COUNT`, psql uses the synchronous `PQexec` function directly on the query, which buffers the entire resultset. But when setting a `FETCH_COUNT`, it will use a cursor-based method with successive fetch calls and freeing or reusing the client-side buffer every `FETCH_COUNT` rows.

So a big resultset should be fetched by a command like:

```
psql -A -t --variable="FETCH_COUNT=10000" \
     -c "select columns from bigtable" \
     > output-file
```

With `FETCH_COUNT` reduced if the rows are very large and it still eats too much memory.

The `-t` stands for `--tuples-only`, which suppresses the output of headers and footers.

Comment: Excellent explanation. I tested both 1) and 2) separately and together.  Turns out that specifying `-A` doesn't make much difference, although my table is simple (i.e. only two number columns) - it might make more difference for a "wider", or variable width table?  Setting `FETCH_COUNT` *does* make all the difference though.

Comment: Yes, the effect of column alignment is more pronounced when the result includes wide text columns of varying lengths. But the point is to remember to turn alignment off  to extract the raw contents rather than look at the space-padded version of them on a terminal.

Comment: It appears from some small experimentation that if you set FETCH_COUNT then it only aligns header sizes based on "largest per column so far" (i.e. if you specify FETCH_COUNT, you don't have to worry much about alignment) FWIW...