# limit user's SELECT query to a fixed number of rows

Tags: postgresql, query, row-level-security, offset-fetch

i have read the following questions:

[Limit Postgres results for a user](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/233307/limit-postgres-results-for-a-user)

and also noted the recommendation of limiting a user's statement_timeout, however i would like something a little more consistent.

noticed one poster on the question mentions that 'row level security' feature would allow someone to enforce this feature.

i have read some tutorials that use row-level security to limit what the user can see by enforcing some column relationship, but i don't know how to extend this to a case of limiting rows since it does not impose any column value constraint.

i also saw this about using FETCH_COUNT:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30369100/how-to-handle-large-result-sets-with-psql

as an *alternative* (key word here):

if row-level security does not allow us to limit the rows returned per-query for a user, it seems a combination of fetch_count and statement_timeout for a specific user may achieve my goal.

is there a way to set the FETCH_COUNT for a user account without having them to specify it in their client/session?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! You do realise that a query with a single response record **could** cripple your entire server if it was some sort of analytic one? See [this](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/5B6EE82A8CF89149BA864458DB605347037C06D74C%40EX-SEA5-A.ant.amazon.com) - also, see [this](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/) - you **can** limit containers' resources - maybe a better approach?

Comment: my solution was to essentially learn ASP.Net core so i can protect my database from being easily copied, whilst allowing the masses to interact with the content much more freely.

not really what i wanted to do, but giving direct DB access is just too much of a risk.

seems to be much more secure to have an ASP.net app that has access to the read-only account locally. 

on that note, on to the next question!